# Which Authentication flow

Tags: authentication, facebook, openid-connect, oauth-2.0

While trying find an Authentication system to add social login to a web service I have a few questions about what I'm supposed to use.  My requirements are:

1. Secure, obviously.
2. Allow users to sign in with at least Google and Facebook, ideally with others like Twitter and LinkedIn
3. Be able to Authenticate users to the back-end service.
4. Users will access the back-end service from either a mobile application or a web-based application.

OpenID Connect sounds like a good fit but it is my understanding that Facebook does not support it.

OAuth2 provides a solution by means of what is sometimes referred to as the Reverse Flow.  This seems fine for the Web Application, but I don't like that it appears that a malicious user can potentially harvest Tokens from another application and use them to impersonate a user.  My understanding is that this is particularly a problem with the Client/Implicit Flow.

Is there a way to secure a client secret in a mobile app?  More specifically can I implement something on the mobile app that allows me to check that my service was in fact the intended Audience for any tokens before accepting them?

Also a second question about the Client ID/client secret:

The client will fetch the user-ID or Email from the Authorization server and send this to the back-end as a means of Identification, but the back-end needs to verify this.  To that end I want to know what else must I send to the back-end?  The Access Token?  Do I use the same client-ID and client-Secret from the Authorization server on both the Client and the back-end to allow the back-end to verify the Access Token?

1. Is there another way?
2. Should I just implement both Openid Connect AND Facebook Connect and call the right one for each user?
3. Would that help in overcoming the issues?

Comment: Auth2 is an authorization (not authentication) protocol. Use OpenId or OpenId Connect.

Comment: See also: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94995/oauth-2-vs-openid-connect-to-secure-api and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/why-use-openid-connect-instead-of-plain-oauth

Comment: If this is a question of authorization and not authentication, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: No the question was about Authentication.  I've found a solution using JWTs and long ago abandoned this idea due to deeper problems (Authenticating by means of an external service implies that that service needs to at least meet the same security level requirements as the target service)